# How JPA Handles Entity within Entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to understand how `JPA` (Using `Hibernate` as `JPA provider`) handles Entity within entity (simple case of one-to-one) and the way tables are created based on the relationship.

To do this, I created two Entities: `VehicleDetails` and `VehicleOwner`, and assuming 1:1 relationship.

The below is the code the Entity classes:

## VehicleDetails:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="VEHICLE_DETAILS")
public class VehicleDetails {

    @Id
    String vehicleRegistrationNum;
    String vehicleMake;
    String vehicleName;

    ...
 }
```

## VehicleOwner:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="VEHICLE_OWNER_DETAILS")
public class VehicleOwner {

    @Id
    @Column(name="SSNID")
    private int ssnID;
    private String ownerName;
    private String vehicleRegistrationNum;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="vehicleRegistrationNum")
    private VehicleDetails vehicleDetails;

       ...
}
```

As can be seen above, `VehicleOwner` has `VehicleDetails` inside it.

The relation we specify using `@OneToOne` annotation. Now, it is where my understanding isn't clear.

I was under the impression that we need to specify a **common field** which is present in these **Entity classes** (and in that attempt I specified "vehicleRegistrationNum") BUT that seems not to be the case.

Rather it was giving me run time exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.example.model.VehicleOwner column: vehicleRegistrationNum
```

I did correct the exception by giving a different name in the @ColumnName, but that is a different issue.

Can anyone help in understand how entity within entity is handled and how the relationship is specified between them?

Comment: Well, you just don't need that vehicleRegistrationNum field in the owner entity. Just drop it. This column, as the message indicates, is already used to map the OneToOne association. And please, post your code as text, in a code block. Not as an image. This makes it impossible for us to copy and paste anything to answer.

Comment: when you give the `@Column` annotation, this is unique. you cant reference an id as integer and in parallel as the other object.  so if you define a `OneToOne`, a join with the other entity will take place, else a simple select for the entity you want.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks for the reply, I have added the code. I still have some doubt. Ok, I will remove the filed  `vehicleRegistrationNum` from the entity `VehicleOwner `. So what does  OneToOne , JoinColumn annotation  on field `private VehicleDetails vehicleDetails` actually mean?  On what field in `VehicleDetails ` does `VehicleOwner ` make relation with? If you can expand your answer it would be great. It seems U turn in what I interpreted all this :(

Comment: it means that when you make a query for `VehicleOwner`, it will make a join with the other table and the `VehicleOwner` object returned - if found- will have the equivalent `VehicleDetails` object.

Comment: @Apostolos: Thanks for the reply.The doubt is, on which field does the relationship happen between these two Objects? Is it the primary key of `VehicleDetails` with which `VehicleOwner` makes the relation? Because in `OneToOne` annotation we don't specify any other info.

Comment: yes it's the primary key.